# XSLT Get First Phone Number From Multi-Line String

Tags: regex, xslt

I have a multi-line string that contains phone numbers. How can I extract the first phone number from the string using XSLT.

My string looks like

```
This is a line
This is another line - 012 345 678
This is another line - 097 654 321
This is another line
```

I need to extract "012 345 678".

Thank you so much.

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version you use? In XSLT 2 or later `(tokenize($string, '\n') ! tokenize(., ' - ')[2])[1]` might do but you haven't explained the possible input formats anyway with a simple sample.

Answer (score -2):

If your XSLT processor supports regex (in other words, if it supports XSLT 2.0 or higher), you can use the expression:

```
replace($theString, '.*?(\d{3} \d{3} \d{3}).*', '$1', 's')
```

to extract the first substring that matches the pattern of `@@@ @@@ @@@`, which will be `012 345 678` in your example.

But you need to be aware that for a string of:

```
This is a line
This is another line - 9012 345 6789
This is another line - 097 654 321
This is another line
```

the result will also be `012 345 678`. If you know which characters can possibly come before and after a phone number, you should add them to the regex pattern.

Comment: May I ask the reason for the downvote?